# Export ER diagrams from SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, erd

I have some ER diagrams created in the development server. I want to export this as PDF and share with my analyst for further usage. The diagram needs to be in PDF format alone since the analyst doesn't have SSMS in his system. I followed the below steps:

1. Generate ER diagram
2. Right click and select 'Copy diagram to clipboard'
3. Paste the copy into paint
4. Save the image as png/jpg and convert to PDF

I am struck in Step 3 since when I paste the ER diagram, I only see the table heading and not the internal column names. Any tools available or any other workaround to make this process easy? any help?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Windows 10 you could  use built-in Microsoft Print to PDF.

SSMS -> Diagram -> Right click -> View Page Breaks -> Place tables in correct way -> Print -> Microsoft Print to PDF

Comment: Any idea to export a PDF as a single (large) page? Even small diagrams are split into multiple pages.

Comment: @JariTurkia That is a good question. I do not have access to SSMS though I would first check if changing paper size helps: MS Print to PDF -> Preferences (Orientation: horizontal) -> Advanced -> A2

Comment: Unfortunately, in Microsoft print to PDF max DPI is 600 and max. paper size is A3.

Answer (score 1):

I also Faced that Same Problem.
You have to Zoom That ErDiagram
and Follow These Steps

- Click anywhere in the diagram area
- Right click -> Copy to clipboard
- Paste it in paint window
- Save it as a png image
- Open browser and search for png to pdf converter online tool
- Convert it to pdf